# The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly. System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

After Migrating a project from 2008 to 2012, while build or rebuild facing this issue.

Detailed Error as follows,

> Error 2   The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The security state of an AppDomain was modified by an AppDomainManager configured with the NoSecurityChanges flag.
>      at System.AppDomain.SetupDomainSecurity(AppDomainHandle appDomain, ObjectHandleOnStack appDomainEvidence, IntPtr creatorsSecurityDescriptor, Boolean publishAppDomain)
>      at System.AppDomain.InitializeDomainSecurity(Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, Boolean generateDefaultEvidence, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor, Boolean publishAppDomain)
>      at System.AppDomain.Setup(Object arg)
>      at System.AppDomain.nCreateDomain(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)
>      at System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomainHelper(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
>      at System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
>      at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)
>      at System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> The “GenerateResource” task failed unexpectedly. System.InvalidOperationException

(*According to the error messages, they are all common errors. I could not give the most direct correct answer for this issue, I can only give you some troubleshootings. In order to avoid losing contact in the round-trip comments, I post those troubleshootings as answer instead of comments.*)

To resolve this issue, please try following methods:

- Add `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>` into the VS2012 DevEnv configuration file, you'll find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`
- Adding the following under the first property group in the Project file:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>true</GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies>
  </ProjectGroup>
  ```
- If you have app.config file in your project, please try to add following into it:

  ```
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
    <legacyCasPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
  ```
- If above not helps you, please try to reinstall the Visual Studio 2012.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Leo Liu-MSFT, As per your suggestions tried but still it remains same. and one more thing it happens only with a few projects.